# Custom caption next to CheckEdit Editor in XtraGrid

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a XtraGrid bound to a Datasource, where I want a single column to have a Check Box in it, and have a caption next to the Check Box in the same cell.  I can get the Checked True or False from another column in the Datasource, and also I need to get the caption text from another column in the Datasource...That part is easy, once I get a handle on implementing the caption changes.

My question is:

How do I programmatically change the text that is displayed next to the CheckEdit in the same cell?

Similar to (Tick and Untick represent the check box state):

```
Tick  Apples
Untick Bananas
```

However, my attempts only display the text 'Check'  - obviously the default caption in the CheckEdit editor:

```
Tick Check
Untick Check
```

I have searched the DevExpress support centre and they only have instructions for the CheckEdit Repository item when used in the TreeList (not the XtraGrid).  I understand it will involve managing the CustomDrawCell event and some others - which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your instructions for `XtraTreeList` can be also applied to `XtraGrid`. But I can suggest to you the other way.
You can use [`GridView.CustomRowCellEdit`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event and two `ResositoryItemCheckEdit` objects:

```cs
private RepositoryItemCheckEdit editTick;
private RepositoryItemCheckEdit editUntick;
```

Just set your `Tick` text to `editTick.Caption` property and `Untick` text to `editUntick.Caption` property.
Here is example:

```cs
//Initialize repository items:
editTick = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit() { GlyphAlignment = HorzAlignment.Near, Caption = "Apples" };
editUntick = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit() { GlyphAlignment = HorzAlignment.Near, Caption = "Bananas" };

//Add handler for CheckedChanged event:
Action<object, EventArgs> action = (s, e) =>
{
    var ownerEdit = s as CheckEdit;

    if (ownerEdit == null)
        return;

    ownerEdit.Text = ownerEdit.Checked ? editTick.Caption : editUntick.Caption;
};

editTick.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(action);
editUntick.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(action);

//Some sample DataSource:
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Bool", typeof(bool));

table.Rows.Add(0, false);
table.Rows.Add(1, false);
table.Rows.Add(2, true);
table.Rows.Add(3, false);
table.Rows.Add(4, true);
table.Rows.Add(5, true);
table.Rows.Add(6, false);
table.Rows.Add(7, true);

gridControl.DataSource = table;

//Here comes the CustomRowCellEdit:
gridView1.CustomRowCellEdit += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "Bool" || e.CellValue == null) //Put your own field name here instead of "Bool".
        return;

    e.RepositoryItem = (bool)e.CellValue ? editTick : editUntick;
};

//Add CustomColumnDisplayText event, so you can see your "Apples" in group rows and filters:
gridView1.CustomColumnDisplayText += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "Bool")
        return;

    e.DisplayText = (bool)e.Value ? editTick.Caption : editUntick.Caption;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, gimme a while to process it (have a long drive ahead of me)

Comment: I tried CustomColumnDisplayText and this does not work with Repository items unfortunately.  I have only about 15 rows so what I did was create 15 repository items of the CheckEdit editor (in a sorted dictionary using the Key from a unique ID in another column of the table).  Then I set the captions for each rep items (and the text colour etc as I need some Red items, and also add event handlers to each rep item) and I use CustomRowCellEdit to assign the appropriate rep items.  +1 for your answer though as it is helpful, many thanks!

Comment: @Grantly `CustomColumnDisplayText` event provides custom display text for column values displayed within `Text Box`-based cells, group rows and filter dropdowns. But this event is not working for `Check Box`-based cells.